# Update from milestone to task Highcharts gantt

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I am trying to update a milestone to a task (and vice-versa). To do so, I update the data and set `milestone: true` and even remove the `end` just to be safe.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qe1kLhw9/2/) you can press the button and the point ***should*** visually update (its values do) but it doesn't and I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if it is not doable to begging with.

Please note that we get a `highcharts-gantt.src.js:48256 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of undefined`.

Also, [you don't get this error](https://jsfiddle.net/qe1kLhw9/3/) when updating from task to milestone.

I'm assuming this may just have been overlooked by the devs and I can probably get a workaround if I post this as an issue on the repo but maybe I'm just doing this wrong to begin with (in some cases, you aren't supposed to update directly but instead use a `setSomething` function).

### Edit

"

Workaround(s):

When updating point, set marker.symbol = null, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oyL24bvq/
Snippet:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].update({
    ...
    marker: {
        symbol: null
    }
});
```

Destroy point.graphic before updating point, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/35vyhqmz/
Snippet:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].graphic = chart.series[0].points[0].graphic.destroy();
```

"

(source: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11158)

Comment: This looks like a bug for me. You should definitely report it on Highcharts github. Check this simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0zjv749q/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Just [did](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11158). Do you mind if I add your simplified demo to the issue ? It may not be necessary but a cleaner code is always better (unfortunately, I am extremely lazy ahah)

Comment: Sure, use it ;) I'll add this workaround there, check it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/34cgnj1y/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel oh nice one, though we still have the issue when [going from task to milestone](https://jsfiddle.net/henfxb6c/), it seems. But hopefully that'll help'em find a fix.

Comment: For me, it looks correctly. What is the issue there?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I added an `else` to the button function in order to toggle back and forth between milestone and task. Initially, it is a milestone -> click once and you get a task -> click again and nothing happens, yet the console properly prints the "new" userOptions for that data. Does it go back to a milestone for you ? I am using "Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: You're right this workaround is not working. Check it on this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tzjd0w86/

Comment: Oh indeed, I didn't think about un-zooming the graph to check for sure

Comment: The dev's found a workaround, I'll update and close my question. We have to either `destroy()` the point, or set it's marker's symbol to `null`.

Comment: Great to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"

Workaround(s):

When updating point, set marker.symbol = null, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oyL24bvq/ Snippet:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].update({
    ...
    marker: {
        symbol: null
    }
});
```

Destroy point.graphic before updating point, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/35vyhqmz/ Snippet:

```
chart.series[0].points[0].graphic = chart.series[0].points[0].graphic.destroy();
```

"

(source: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11158)